# How to create consecutive columns (R)

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I have prescription record data and would like to find out how many prescriptions each person had in each year from their issue date until the end of their record.  Example data (first 5 rows of each ID):

```
     ID Issue_Date index.date other.drugs
  1:  1 2000-02-08 2011-02-03           1
  2:  1 2000-04-04 2011-02-03           0
  3:  1 2000-05-30 2011-02-03           1
  4:  1 2000-07-25 2011-02-03           1
  5:  1 2000-08-22 2011-02-03           1
 ---                                     
  1:  2 2007-03-23 2009-04-03           1
  2:  2 2007-04-04 2009-04-03           1
  3:  2 2007-04-23 2009-04-03           1
  4:  2 2007-04-23 2009-04-03           0
  5:  2 2007-05-21 2009-04-03           1
```

the `other.drugs` column is an indicator variable that shows whether the prescription given on that date is not a prescription of interest in the study.  the `index.date` is the date they entered the study.  There are more than 1000 `ID`'s, and only 2 are given here.

I want to find the sum of the `other.drugs` per year for every year after their `issue.date`.  I calculated this separately for the first year using the below code:

```
dt <- dt[, yearend.1 := Issue_Date[1]+365, by = ID]
dt <- dt[(Issue_Date<=yearend.1), comorbid.1 := sum(other.drugs), by = ID]
dt <- dt[, comorbid.1:= comorbid.1[!is.na(comorbid.1)][1], by = ID]
# the last line copies the value to each cell the ID occupies in the data.table for that column instead of having NA's
```

And this gave the following result:

```
     ID Issue_Date index.date other.drugs  yearend.1 comorbid.1
  1:  1 2000-02-08 2011-02-03           1 2001-02-07          8
  2:  1 2000-04-04 2011-02-03           1 2001-02-07          8
  3:  1 2000-05-30 2011-02-03           1 2001-02-07          8
  4:  1 2000-07-25 2011-02-03           1 2001-02-07          8
  5:  1 2000-08-22 2011-02-03           1 2001-02-07          8
---
  1:  2 2007-03-23 2009-04-03           1 2008-03-22         30
  2:  2 2007-04-04 2009-04-03           1 2008-03-22         30
  3:  2 2007-04-23 2009-04-03           1 2008-03-22         30
  4:  2 2007-04-23 2009-04-03           1 2008-03-22         30
  5:  2 2007-05-21 2009-04-03           1 2008-03-22         30
```

Interpretation: ID 1 was prescribed 8 other drugs in the year after their first `issue_date`, and ID 2 was prescribed 30.

For years 2-10 (there is a maximum of 11 years of records) I wrote the following loop:

```
years <- seq(730, 3650, 365)
# number of days in 2-10 years.
years2 <- seq(2,10,1)
# numbering the years for column names
colnames <- paste0("yearend.", years2)
colnames2 <- paste0("comorbid.", years2)
# names of columns to be used

for (i in 1:length(years)) {
  dt <- dt[, colnames[i] := Issue_Date[1]+years[i], by = ID]
  dt <- dt[(Issue_Date>=(as.Date(colnames[i], "%d-%m-%Y")) & Issue_Date<(as.Date(colnames[i+1], "%d-%m-%Y"))), 
         colnames2[i] := sum(other.drugs), by = ID]
  dt <- dt[, colnames2[i]:= colnames2[i][!is.na(colnames2[i])][1], by = ID]
}
```

However the new columns that should have been created are:

```
     ID Issue_Date index.date other.drugs  yearend.1 comorbid.1  yearend.2 comorbid.2  yearend.3 comorbid.3
  1:  1 2000-02-08 2011-02-03           1 2001-02-07          8 2002-02-07 comorbid.2 2003-02-07 comorbid.3
  2:  1 2000-04-04 2011-02-03           1 2001-02-07          8 2002-02-07 comorbid.2 2003-02-07 comorbid.3 
  3:  1 2000-05-30 2011-02-03           1 2001-02-07          8 2002-02-07 comorbid.2 2003-02-07 comorbid.3
  4:  1 2000-07-25 2011-02-03           1 2001-02-07          8 2002-02-07 comorbid.2 2003-02-07 comorbid.3
  5:  1 2000-08-22 2011-02-03           1 2001-02-07          8 2002-02-07 comorbid.2 2003-02-07 comorbid.3 
 ---
```

I would like to know what is going wrong with my loop.  Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to use a column name in a `data.table` which actually comes from a variable in R, you need to use `get`. Thus you should rewrite your loop like this,

```
for (i in 1:length(years)) {
  dt <- dt[, colnames[i] := Issue_Date[1]+years[i], by = ID]
  dt <- dt[(Issue_Date>=(as.Date(get(colnames[i]), "%d-%m-%Y")) & Issue_Date<(as.Date(get(colnames[i+1]), "%d-%m-%Y"))), 
         colnames2[i] := sum(other.drugs), by = ID]
  dt <- dt[, colnames2[i]:= get(colnames2[i])[!is.na(get(colnames2[i]))][1], by = ID]
}
```

I couldn't actually test your code as it is, since I had 2 problems:

- I didn't have enough data so that I would get anything from your temporal condition `Issue_Date>...`
- Maybe I'm missing something, but in your loop you are trying to use `colnames[i+1]`, i.e `yearend.X` before it is actually created (maybe you've run it several times and that's why you don't get an error?)

I did something like this to test it, of course the values of `comorbid.2` do not make sense:

```
dt
    ID Issue_Date index.date other.drugs yearend.1 comorbid.1
 1:  1   00-02-08 2011-02-03           1  01-02-07          4
 2:  1   00-04-04 2011-02-03           0  01-02-07          4
 3:  1   00-05-30 2011-02-03           1  01-02-07          4
 4:  1   00-07-25 2011-02-03           1  01-02-07          4
 5:  1   00-08-22 2011-02-03           1  01-02-07          4
 6:  2   07-03-23 2009-04-03           1  08-03-22          4
 7:  2   07-04-04 2009-04-03           1  08-03-22          4
 8:  2   07-04-23 2009-04-03           1  08-03-22          4
 9:  2   07-04-23 2009-04-03           0  08-03-22          4
10:  2   07-05-21 2009-04-03           1  08-03-22          4

i <- 1
dt <- dt[, colnames[i] := Issue_Date[1]+years[i], by = ID]
dt <- dt[Issue_Date<get(colnames[i]), 
         colnames2[i] := sum(other.drugs), by = ID]
dt <- dt[, colnames2[i]:= get(colnames2[i])[!is.na(get(colnames2[i]))][1], by = ID]

dt
    ID Issue_Date index.date other.drugs yearend.1 comorbid.1 yearend.2 comorbid.2
 1:  1   00-02-08 2011-02-03           1  01-02-07          4  02-02-07          4
 2:  1   00-04-04 2011-02-03           0  01-02-07          4  02-02-07          4
 3:  1   00-05-30 2011-02-03           1  01-02-07          4  02-02-07          4
 4:  1   00-07-25 2011-02-03           1  01-02-07          4  02-02-07          4
 5:  1   00-08-22 2011-02-03           1  01-02-07          4  02-02-07          4
 6:  2   07-03-23 2009-04-03           1  08-03-22          4  09-03-22          4
 7:  2   07-04-04 2009-04-03           1  08-03-22          4  09-03-22          4
 8:  2   07-04-23 2009-04-03           1  08-03-22          4  09-03-22          4
 9:  2   07-04-23 2009-04-03           0  08-03-22          4  09-03-22          4
10:  2   07-05-21 2009-04-03           1  08-03-22          4  09-03-22          4
```

Hope it helps.